# How to change file ownership of DB backup in SQL Server container

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker

I'm following this guide to restore a database backup
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/tutorial-restore-backup-in-sql-server-container?view=sql-server-ver15

I used docker cp command to copy the DB backup files to the container
    docker exec -it SQLContainer mkdir /var/opt/mssql/backup

```
docker cp MyDb.bak SQLContainer:/var/opt/mssql/backup/
```

However when trying to restore the DB by running the following query in SSMS, an error message is shown

```
RESTORE DATABASE MyDB FROM DISK='/var/opt/mssql/backup/MyDB.bak'

Operating system error 5(Access is denied.).
```

I tried copying using docker cp -a, which sets file ownership to same as destination, but I got this error.

```
docker cp -a MyDb.bak SQLContainer:/var/opt/mssql/backup/

Error response from daemon: getent unable to find entry "mssql" in passwd database
```

I'm using Microsoft's image and I don't know the password for root user, the container runs using mssql user, so chown doesn't work either. How can I change the file permissions so DB restore works?

Comment: Does the directory `/var/opt/mssql/backup/` actually exist in the container? I recall that it doesn't by default. If you copied it, without creating it, the files may not have actually been copied across.

Comment: I don't think this is permission related. Add the commands you ran to your question.

Comment: @DanGuzman: It's definitely permission related, same problem people have reported but was solvable on Windows Server. I have added commands to the question.

Comment: @Larnu: The directory exists, was created before.

Comment: @stormtrooper, I successfully ran a restore using Docker Desktop for Windows by running these commands from PowerShell copy/pasted from the tutorial. The only thing I changed was the backup file name to one I had on my host system. 1) docker run, `docker exec -it sql1 mkdir /var/opt/mssql/backup`, 3) `docker cp c:\temp\test.bak sql1:/var/opt/mssql/backup`, 4) `docker exec -it sql1 /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P "<YourStrong!Passw0rd>" -Q "RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = '/var/opt/mssql/backup/test.bak'"`

Comment: @stormtrooper, I just noticed you did not specify `WITH MOVE` on your `RESTORE` command. If not specified, SQL Server will try to restore the db files to the original backup location.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out when I copied the database backup files from the Windows host to the Ubuntu machine, the files were owned by root user and all other users didn't have read permission.
Adding read permission to the file before copying to the docker container works and the server was able to read the files.

```
sudo chmod a+r MyDb.bak

sudo docker cp MyDb.bak SQLContainer:/var/opt/mssql/backup/
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue just today, about the same time as this incident, just attaching MDF and LDF files.

By doing the chmod go+w before copying files **without the -a** I was able to get SQL Server to treat them as writeable. Prior to that I was getting error messages whenever any update was performed.